# Javascript, factorial , too difficult

Tags: javascript

```
  var fact = (function(){
  var cache =  {'0': 1};

  var func = function(n){
    var result = 0;
    if(typeof(cache[n]) === 'number'){
      result = cache[n];
    }
    else{
      result = cache[n] = n * func(n-1);
    }
    return result;
  }


  return func;
})();

  console.log(fact(5)); //120
```

The code is this.
I can't understand this code, wholly.
It's look like add cache, and add cache
but how does this work?
Don't we need for loop to add cache?

also, return func; <- what's is this?
please explain wholly

Comment: my coumputer work well

Comment: Fact is an iife (immediately-invoked function expression) that returns `func`. Since JavaScript supports first class functions, that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is more complex than is needed.  The cache array isn't being used as cache; it's being used as a means of hardcoding the fact that the factorial of 0 is 1.  The recursion loop doesn't need to add to the cache, but if the extra line to do so were added, then the array would really function as a cache, and it would provide performance improvements on subsequent calls to the function.